# Python - Create string from list of list of characters

Tags: python, string, list

I got stuck in returning a string from a list of list of characters.

```
[['h', 'i', 'i', 'u', 'i', 'h'], 
 ['r', 'm'], ['h', 'g', 'i', 'z', 'g', 'v', 't', 'b'], 
 ['x', 'z', 'm', 'm', 'l', 'g'], ['y', 'v'], 
 ['x', 'l', 'i', 'i', 'v', 'x', 'g'], 
 ['g', 's', 'i', 'l', 'f', 't', 's'], 
 ['g', 'z', 'x', 'g', 'r', 'x', 'z', 'o'], 
 ['n', 'z', 'm', 'v', 'f', 'e', 'v', 'i', 'h']]
```

My expected output is:

```
'hiiuih rm hgizgvtb xzmmlg yv xliivxg gsilfts gzxgrxzo nzmvfevih'
```

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Comment: share your code.

Comment: `' '.join(''.join(x) for x in lst)`?

Comment: *what* string? `str(lst)` will return *a string* (but no doubt not the one you want), also show your efforts please

Comment: try this `''.join([str for group in my_list for str in group])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a *list comprehension* in combination with `join` method.

```
result = ' '.join([''.join(item) for item in my_list])
```

Output

```
'hiiuih rm hgizgvtb xzmmlg yv xliivxg gsilfts gzxgrxzo nzmvfevih'
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming level one is words, level two is letters:

```
foo = [['h', ...], ...]
" ".join("".join(w) for w in foo)
```

Gives

```
'hiiuih rm hgizgvtb xzmmlg yv xliivxg gsilfts gzxgrxzo nzmvfevih'
```